# Join in Pivot tabel Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I have following tables:

**Food:**

- Foodid(pk)
- FoodName
- FoodImage
- Description

**Categories:**

- Category_id(pk)
- CategoryName

**Restaurant**

- Res_id(pk)
- ResName
- Address

**category_food_restaurant**

- Category_id(fk)
- Food_id(fk)
- Res_id(fk)

Now I want to show Food items based on category name.For that I make query as:

```
$Category = DB::table('Food')
                ->select('Food.Food_id','Food.FoodName',
                        'Food.FoodImage','Categories.CategoryName')
                ->join('Categories','Categories.Category_id',
                        '=','category_food_restauarant.Category_id')
                ->where('Categories.CategoryName', 
                        '=','Breakfast')->get();
```

But this gives me error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Food.Category_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `Food`.`Food_id`, `Food`.`FoodName`, `Food`.`FoodImage`, `Categories`.`CategoryName` from `Food` inner join `Categories` on `Categories`.`Category_id` = `Food`.`Category_id` where `Categories`.`CategoryName` = Breakfast).

Where is the problem.How I can show food items based on category by using these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining `Food` table and `Categories` table but there is no relation between them directly. So you have to join these two tables through `category_food_restaurant`. The following should work:

```
DB::table('category_food_restaurant')
            ->select('Food.Food_id','Food.FoodName',
                    'Food.FoodImage','Categories.CategoryName')
            ->join('Categories','Categories.Category_id',
                    '=','category_food_restaurant.Category_id')
            ->join('Food','Food.Food_id',
                    '=','category_food_restaurant.Food_id')
            ->where('Categories.CategoryName', 
                    '=','Breakfast')->get();
```

Comment: It gives error:SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'foody.category_food_restauarant' doesn't exist (SQL: select `Food`.`Food_id`, `Food`.`FoodName`, `Food`.`FoodImage`, `Categories`.`CategoryName` from `category_food_restauarant` inner join `Categories` on `Categories`.`Category_id` = `category_food_restauarant`.`Category_id` inner join `Food` on `Food`.`Food_id` = `category_food_restauarant`.`Food_id` where `Categories`.`CategoryName` = Breakfast)

Comment: I think I mistook the spelling of the table name. It should be `category_food_restaurant`.

Comment: yes there is problem in spelling.now it works.Thanx alot

Comment: Could you update the answer for when working with eloquent or should I post a new question?